# Why are there different binary blobs for different versions of Android running on the same Nexus device

Tags: android

There are multiple versions of Android that are compatible with each Nexus device - for example 4.4 to 6.0 are compatible with the nexus 5.

Although the OS is changing, the hardware is constant, yet there are different binary blobs for the hardware for each OS version. Why is that ?

Since Android is developed independently (by google), why should the binary blobs (developed by the hardware manufacturers) for the hardware change ? Is it intentional (to fix some bugs / optimise the hardware ) ? What is wrong with using older blobs with a newer OS ? Since the HAL is constant, shouldn't it NOT matter if you use an older blob with a newer OS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons: one is to fix bugs and make improvements, as you mentioned. The other is that Android's interface to the binary blobs changes with each version, so the blobs need to be updated to offer the new interface.